# Inverse prediction of SVM because AUC is lower than 0.5

Tags: svm, auc, inverse-prediction

I am training SVM by a dataset with 8 features using 10-fold CV. 
The **AUC for testing data** is under 0.5. I remember that somewhere it had been written that in cases with `AUC < 0.5`, we can inverse the answer of the classifier to test samples. For example, in a two class problem, if SVM predicts class '1' for a test sample, we consider it as class '2'.
Is it correct?

Comment: How much below .5? If it is very far below .5, I would speculate there is a code error. If it is .493, this might just indicate chance performance because there is no pattern detectable by an SVM of the kind you're applying in the data.

Comment: It is about 0.4-0.46. Indeed, I do not expect to get high AUC with these features, but I do not expect to get AUC below 0.5 too.

Answer (score 3):

Yes- mathematically, in a two-class problem where the AUC is < .05, the prediction of the model can be reversed to get a better AUC fit on any (one) set of data.

That said- if you're getting an AUC this low (worse than chance) on the test set, the model is more-or-less telling you that it cannot (1) determine a useful relationship between the variables and/or (2) that the relationships the model is using are not generalizable outside of the training set- i.e. the model is over-fitting to training noise.

Since you seem to know in this case that you have weak features- it indicates to me that the model may be fitting *only* to training noise. That is, your features are not informative of the class separation and only random variation is being modeled. I can't say this for certain without contextual information, but it would be one reasonable hypothesis to be tested in this situation.