# Training AUC below 0.5

Tags: logistic, roc, auc

I've trained a logistic regression using a small number of predictors - pseudo R-squared is only 0.1 but I have significant terms and a nice low p value for the model. However, *even on its own training data*, the AUC for the model is only 0.28:

[image: ROC curve of the model]

I thought this was impossible, and my only intuition for what's going on is that the class imbalance (only 5% of the observations are in the positive class) means that the no information rate is pretty high. I still think my model should beat random guessing, at least on its own training data.

I assumed this was a coding error but I think I've ruled that out now, so **can anyone explain to me how this is possible?!**

I've looked for other discussions on here, most seem to focus on AUC < 0.5 on the test set which I can can more easily understand (e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196659/inverse-prediction-of-svm-because-auc-is-lower-than-0-5) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297231/auc-score-less-than-0-5-for-logistic-regression)). [This one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266387/can-auc-roc-be-between-0-0-5) came the closest, demonstrating that a predictor that's really just noise can come out below 0.5 - but I think my model has found some real relationships in the data...

Comment: Switch the labels. :)

Comment: Thanks @usεr11852 but I've tried flipping the labels, respecifying the target variables and other coding errors but I just keep reproducing this result.

Comment: Thanks @Sycorax, I'd get that if my terms were all insignificant, but given I've got significant terms and a decent p value for the model overall, seems like there's some signal in the features. I realise I haven't shared enough to rule out a code error, but I've satisfied myself it's unlikely.

Comment: That's a good clue but I'm not fully understanding. My expectation at least would be that significant terms should tend to rank order the observations correctly. Is there a link you could throw me on this @Sycorax?

Comment: Thanks but I know what the 2 concepts mean, and that they're different, but surely one leads to the other? I was actually referring to the p value of the whole model, but let's say it's a model with a single significant linear predictor. The fact that the model achieves a good fit with that variable, should mean that predictions based on that linear relationship tend to rank order the observations better than randomly too. And in any case, not worse! :-)

Comment: @usεr11852 you were totally right - the labels were still flipped in the final plotting command, the one bit of code I didn't check - silly me, thanks for your help

Comment: No worries Tom, it has happened to all of us in the past too. :) (I will write it as an answer so the question isn't unanswered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AUC-ROC can be below 0.5 but when it is substantially below 0.5 as in the case shown here (~0.28) there is a good chance that the labels are flipped/reversed at some point in our modelling pipeline. Such a low AUC-ROC score would suggest we are *consistently* bad, it can happen, but usually we are *just* bad!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out this *was* a coding error, here's the correct ROC curve:
[image]
with AUC of 0.72.

Moral of the story: if you see this, triple- and quadruple-check your code, because it *is* impossible.